# CSS strange lines appearing when I use the Transform: scale property

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I am currently working on a website [www.allsocial.app](http://www.allsocial.app). If you scroll down so the section with the pricing, I have added a zigzag pattern via CSS code to create this effect. The center column is normal size, and the columns for the startup and professional package is made smaller using transform: scale(0.85).

The problem is that some weird lines have appeared when I scale them to make it smaller. I haven't been able to figure this out and the reason for these strange lines. At first, I thought they were borders but that doesn't seem to be the case.

This is the code I use to create the zigzag pattern.

```
.allsocial__standard-price:after, .allsocial__basic-price:after, .allsocial__premium-price:after {
    
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 16px, transparent 0), linear-gradient(45deg, #ffffff 16px, transparent 0);
    background-position: left-bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 15px 32px;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    
}
```

And this is the code I use to scale the elements.

```
.allsocial__premium-container {
    transform: scale(0.85);
    transform-origin: 10% 50%;
}
```

If anyone knows what is the cause of these strange lines, then that would be appreciated.

I have tried border: none as I was thinking they were borders. I have also tried adding some borders, but again, this just makes it worse

I have also tried changing the linear gradient angle, but then I don't achieve the effect I want. I have also tried changing the linear gradient transparency levels.

Comment: Please provide a working snippet for your problem.

Comment: The website is built using Elementor page builder, with custom CSS added to it. Because of this, unfortunately, I can't provide a working snippet. You can view the website at www.allsocial.app to be able to see the issue

Comment: Could you extract just enough code to demonstrate the problem? You can find the actual HTML and CSS using your browser's devtools inspect facility and you can put a runnable snippet into your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Doing this might even help you find the problem.

Comment: Actually, the code you give, plus a relevant div, is enough to show the problem (at least on Edge/Windows10) so make it into a snippet we can run. Thanks.